# Reset the categories of categorical index in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with a column being categorical.

I remove all the rows having one the categories.

How can I make sure the resulting dataframe has only those categories that exist and does not keep the deleted categories in its index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'color':np.random.choice(['Blue','Green','Brown','Red'], 50)})

df.color = df.color.astype('category')

df.color.head()
```

Output:

```
0     Blue
1    Green
2     Blue
3    Green
4    Brown
Name: color, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [Blue, Brown, Green, Red]
```

Remove Brown from dataframe and category.

```
df = df.query('color != "Brown"')

df.color = df.color.cat.remove_categories('Brown')

df.color.head()
```

Output:

```
0     Blue
1    Green
2     Blue
3    Green
7      Red
Name: color, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [Blue, Green, Red]
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make sure the resulting dataframe has only those categories that exist and does not keep the deleted categories in its index?

There's (now?) a pandas function doing exactly that: [`remove_unused_categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.remove_unused_categories.html)

This function only has one parameter `inplace`, which is deprecated since pandas 1.2.0. Hence, the following example (based on [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47879633/3410474)) does not use `inplace`:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'color':np.random.choice(['Blue','Green','Brown','Red'], 50)})
... df.color = df.color.astype('category')
... df.color.head()
0    Green
1    Brown
2     Blue
3      Red
4    Brown
Name: color, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [Blue, Brown, Green, Red]

>>> df = df[df.color != "Brown"]
... df.color = df.color.cat.remove_unused_categories()
... df.color.head()
0    Green
2     Blue
3      Red
5      Red
6    Green
Name: color, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [Blue, Green, Red]
```